# How to fix sudo due to some issues with the user?

Tags: centos, sudo, journalctl

My system based on CentOS. When I am running command with a `sudo` I got and error:
for example I am trying to restart nginx:

```
-> sudo systemctl restart nginx
[sudo] password for rd\eldar.nafajov: 
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

And running the command `journalctl -xe` outputs:

```
Dec 14 00:20:18 a-26h5d9kblflz2 sudo[30801]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): authentication failure; logname=rd\eldar.nafajov uid=66741 euid=0 tty=/dev/pts/0 ruser=rd\eldar.nafajov rhost=
```

The last steps before I was doing some privileges change for some folders in the var or etc directory, not remember exactly and set that folders with `chmod -R 777` .

So maybe there some way to reset privileges for folders by default and fix the `sudo` with the username ?

Comment: Also getting this issue as well : `pam_unix(polkit-1:auth): authentication failure`

Comment: Is your username actually `=rd\eldar.nafajov`? This can certainly cause problems.

Comment: @doneal24 actually no, how to check the original username just to be sure there is no `=rd\` ?

Comment: It seems your username is `rd\eldar.nafajov` and I think  `\\` is causing problems. [Characters in usernames](https://serverfault.com/questions/73084/what-characters-should-i-use-or-not-use-in-usernames-on-linux)